# New to Ubuntu. Issues on Printer, Scanner and others on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, printing, scanner, canon

I have installed UBUNTU on my laptop. I am enjoying the features. However, being Newbie to LINUX world I was not sure I could find solutions easily. But, I am so excited that all answers to my queries were available. Thank you all!

I found a few problems which I solved by searching for resources [WIFI, Keyboard Mouse, or screen hang, etc]. They are solved but unable to find drivers for two more devices.

I have CANON LBP 2900 Printer and Canon LiDe100 Scanner. I tried to find out solutions here in this portal but could not find any. Some instructions I followed for printer did not help whereas for scanner there was none.

As well as software, I need to install Grammarly, Electrum, Whatsapp. Whatsapp, I will use a browser as well as for Grammarly too. I need help to install Electrum Wallet, as the instruction I followed in this [link](https://electrum.org/#download) did not help to install the program properly.

As a Newbie to the LINUX world, I need to learn many commands. And, with the help of you all, I may learn soon.

Thank you and hope to get solution.

Regards, 
Dipendra

Comment: What went wrong when you tried to install electrum?

Comment: I was able to use it from the terminal, and on Ubuntu GUI I could not find it installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the grammarly chrome extension. To do this you must have google chrome or chromium as your browser. Chromium is open source, while google chrome is a proprietary version of chromium.

To install chromium type this in a new terminal window:

```
sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade    
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

To install google chrome type the following in a new terminal window:

```
sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

then install the program using `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

---

To install Electrum Bitcoin Wallet, issue the following commands into terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

the download the package

```
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.8/Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz
```

verify the signature

```
wget https://download.electrum.org/3.3.8/Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz.asc
gpg --verify Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz.asc
```

finally install with PIP

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools python3-pip
python3 -m pip install --user Electrum-3.3.8.tar.gz[fast]
```

If the above installation didn't work, try the following:

1. Download the electrum bitcoin wallet appimage. Go to the [downloads](https://electrum.org/#download) page and select Appimage next to Linux.
2. Make the appimage executable and then run it

For instructions on how to use an appimage and run it, see this [article](https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/).

Comment: For Electrum, I am still facing the problem. 

Grammarly, I will test it today. 

Thank you and regards!

Comment: Electrum installation with PIP output >

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (45.2.0-1).
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
7 not upgraded! Will this effect the installation?

Comment: It shouldn't. Just to be safe run `sudo apt update&&sudo apt upgrade` before attempting installation

Comment: @Idias I will uninstall, reboot, run this command and then install again. Hopefully, it will work. 

Thank you and Regards

Comment: @Idias I am sorry, running this command before installation also did not help. The problem persists. Electrum Wallet do not show within Ubuntu Software installed list.

Comment: @DipendraKumarSahay I edited my question, please try again and let me know if it works

Comment: @Idias, I have followed your edited response. The problem persists. Using Terminal, I am able to access Electrum.

Comment: Maybe reach out to support? https://electrum.org/#community

Comment: @Idias, yes I must reach them. I have not thought this, thank you again. Greetings!

Comment: @DipendraKumarSahay Glad to help

Answer (score 3):

I can help with the Whatsapp application.

Download whatsdesk from the Ubuntu Software centre.

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help. I installed it and hopefully, it works fine. :) 

Regards
Dipendra

Comment: I know it didn't fully answer your question but might you consider upvoting my response which might help others with the same question?

Comment: I can understand, I tried to UPVOTE too. But, it gives me a message which I have a screenshot but I don't know to paste here. 

The message is 
'Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.'

I think this means I am new in this forum and my votes are counted but not displayed.

Comment: Well, I just upvoted your question to get you underway. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks and my best regards to you.

Answer (score 2):

Most drivers are installed automatically on Ubuntu, but sometimes you need to download straight from the manufacturer, in your case https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900.html

Double click on the *deb should install the drivers. Or you can unpack to your disk and type

```
sudo apt install ./somefile.deb
```

Comment: Apt also installs local files. BONUS: It resolves dependencies, too. `sudo apt install the_file_name.deb`

Comment: Hey! I explored the website link and found the drivers for Linux x64 are LBP6020 to LBP7210Cdn. Are you sure this is the correct driver for LBP2900 i-SENSYS [CANON]?

Comment: Here is my test report. First, Ubuntu recognizes the printer 'Canon LBP2900 i-SENSYS'. I tested the installed driver but it does not print. It shows dependencies error. 

Therefore, I removed the previous installation completely, then I followed step-by-step instruction [your's suggestion]. The installation is a success. It does not show any dependencies error. I then sent a test print, the message was 'Printing successful'. 

Oops! The printer has no action. :P Where did it go wrong?

Comment: For the Canon printer, try in terminal "sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint" followed by "system-config-printer"

Comment: @AndreasF I will try this too and will update the output. Thank you and regards!